# Mic is not working in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: 18.04, microphone

I am new to Ubuntu. Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and now my mic is not working. I tried to fix the issue but, I would not be able to fix my problem by going through some available solutions over internet.

So, here is the issue: When I'm speaking on google meet or zoom, my team member is not able to hear me (I can hear them).

I tried using an earphone but still my colleagues are not able to hear me in meetings (The earphone is working fine with the mobile phone/other laptop).

My laptop is hp pavilion g4, OS Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. Please help me with what can I do to get my mic working!

I have seen in the other posts people are requesting the results of "inxi -Fxz", "aplay -l" and "dmesg | grep snd", so I have added these that can be found below.

**inxi -Fxz**

```
System:    Host: vs-pc Kernel: 5.4.0-122-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.5.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4)
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP Pavilion g4 Notebook PC v: 0691130000204610000610100 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 3564 v: 21.46 serial: N/A
           BIOS: Insyde v: F.6A date: 05/13/2013
Battery    BAT0: charge: 6.9 Wh 18.3% condition: 37.7/37.7 Wh (100%)
           model: Hewlett-Packard Primary status: Discharging
CPU:       Dual core AMD A4-3330MX APU with Radeon HD Graphics (-MCP-) 
           arch: Fusion rev.0 cache: 2048 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4a svm) bmips: 8783
           clock speeds: max: 2200 MHz 1: 1561 MHz 2: 1382 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Sumo [Radeon HD 6480G]
           bus-ID: 00:01.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.8 ) driver: radeon
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.07hz
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD SUMO (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-122-generic, LLVM 10.0.0)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:14.2
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:01.1
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.4.0-122-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath9k bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCIE Fast Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169 port: 2000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-3: Atheros usb-ID: 006-002
           IF: null-if-id state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 542.9GB (2.8% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SK_hynix_SC300B size: 512.1GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: Ultra size: 30.8GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 469G used: 12G (3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 75.1C mobo: N/A gpu: 77.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 239 Uptime: 18 min Memory: 2035.2/5415.2MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: N/A
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201) inxi: 2.3.56
```

**aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: 92HD81B1X5 Analog [92HD81B1X5 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**dmesg | grep snd**

```
[    5.822103] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for 92HD81B1X5: line_outs=1 (0xd/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.822107] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.822108] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0xb/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.822114] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.822115] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    5.822117] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x11
[    5.822119] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0xc
```

**pacmd list-sources**

```
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 16.00 .. 371.52 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 8
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0340000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "780d"
        device.product.name = "FCH Azalia Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB
            balance -1.00
    base volume: 8739 /  13% / -52.50 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 1.62 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 24.99 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "92HD81B1X5 Analog"
        alsa.id = "92HD81B1X5 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0340000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "780d"
        device.product.name = "FCH Azalia Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "IDT 92HD81B1X5"
        alsa.components = "HDA:111d7605,103c3564,00100107"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-internal-mic>
```

Please help me to fix this.
Thanks you in advance!

Comment: why 18.04? that goes EOL in a year, why not use a later version (22.04 being the latest and will be supported for 5 years)

Comment: @Esther I'll install 22.04 if installing 22.04 resolve my mic issue.

Comment: Try 22.04 from a LiveUSB and check it.